# How to make FileZilla save to SFTP server WITHOUT a propmt?

Tags: file-management, remote, text-editing, sftp

Every time I save a file from the server, it will pop up a "File has changed" prompt, and ask me if I want to upload to server. How can I stop it from asking me? Fugu would do it automatically, and it is so convenient.

Answer (score 3):

The FileZilla developers have decided to make users confirm the prompt *every single time*. It's a long-standing debate between users and the developers, but the developers seem to have their minds made up.

See these posts for details on the issue, workarounds and patches:

- http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/4694
- http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=14672
- http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/2992
- http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/5157

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the menu and click Edit > Settings, you should be able to set the default actions.

I can't imagine the fact you are using SFTP would make much of a difference.

[image]

Comment: But i did change this setting, uploads is to overwrite

Comment: Did you change both the upload and download columns?